# Constructing a union tuple in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, unions

Tuples are kind of [like structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852261/c-tuple-vs-struct). Are there also tuples that behave like unions? Or unions where I can access the members like in tuples, e.g.

```
my_union_tuple<int, char> u;
get<1>(u);
get<int>(u); // C++14 only, or see below
```

For the 2nd line, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594002/for-stdtuple-how-to-get-data-by-type-and-how-to-get-type-by-index).

Of course, the solution should not only work for a specific union, like `<int, char>`, but for arbitrary types and number of types.

Comment: These are called variants. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/variant/) has an implementation of one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No `std::tuple<A, B>` means A AND B.
If you want a typesafe union-like container, have a look to [boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).

```
boost::variant<int, std::string> v;

v = "hello";
std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

It does provide safe traversing with visitors:

```
class times_two_visitor
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:

    void operator()(int & i) const
    {
        i *= 2;
    }

    void operator()(std::string & str) const
    {
        str += str;
    }

};
```

Or even direct accessors that can throw if the type is not good:

```
std::string& str = boost::get<std::string>(v);
```

(Code taken from [boost variant basic tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic))

Comment: Thanks, sounds correct. From looking at the headers, I guess boost does not use variadic lists, but typelists? (the C++03 equivalent)

Comment: @Johannes I do not know. Boost machinery is heavily dependant of the compiler and as they do support very old ones there is certainly more than one implementation.